# YouTube API v3 sample project raising GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain -32602 unauthorized error

Tags: objective-c, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I have just downloaded the [Google API objective C client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/checkout). I opened the YouTube example project in Xcode on my Mac. It builds and runs without errors.

I registered a project with [Google APIs](https://code.google.com/apis/console), and created a Client ID for installed applications, choosing iOS and entering the sample code's Bundle ID, com.example.YouTubeSample. I left the App Store ID blank and deep linking disabled.

I entered the resulting Client ID and Client secrets into the sample app.  I signed myself into Google through the app's window too, and it tells me I am signed in.

I then uploaded a 85kb .mov file. When it finished, it gave me the error:

```
Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=-32602 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Unauthorized)" UserInfo=0x...
   {error=Unauthorized, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Unauthorized), 
    GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x...: 
    {message:"Unauthorized" data:[1] code:-32602}}
```

(Since the sample app is for Mac OS, not iOS, I also tried creating a second Client ID in Google APIs, for an installed application of type "other".  I entered this new ID and secret into the sample app, and when I uploaded the .mov file I got the same error.)

Over in the API console, I see an error report showing 5 Error code 400s and 2 error code 500s.

What have I done wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the reason for this error was very simple. My google account did not have a YouTube channel associated with it.

However, with that fixed I am now getting a different error message (code -32602, "bad request").  I will post a new question for that.

Comment: Hey, when you say Youtube channel not associated, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Hi, yes, both issues were resolved in the end. The unauthorized error just required me to go into YouTube and set up a channel at my google account. [Here is a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930793/youtube-api-v3-sample-project-raising-gtljsonrpcerrordomain-32602-bad-request-e) to my second post about the bad request - basically I just restarted Xcode and it worked.