# YouTube API v3 sample project raising GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain -32602 bad request error

Tags: objective-c, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I have just downloaded the [Google API objective C client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/checkout). I opened the YouTube example project in Xcode on my Mac. It builds and runs without errors.

I registered a project with [Google APIs](https://code.google.com/apis/console), and created a Client ID for installed applications, choosing iOS and entering the sample code's Bundle ID, com.example.YouTubeSample. I left the App Store ID blank and deep linking disabled.

I entered the resulting Client ID and Client secrets into the sample app. I signed myself into Google through the app's window too, and it tells me I am signed in.

Independently I went to YouTube and uploaded a 1Mb .mov file, which uploads fine (although it tells me there may be an audio/video sync issue).

I then uploaded the same file through the sample app. When it finished, it gave me the error:

```
Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=-32602 
   "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Bad Request)" 
   UserInfo=0x.... {error=Bad Request, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Bad Request), 
   GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x...: 
   {message:"Bad Request" data:[1] code:-32602}}
```

(Since the sample app is for Mac OS, not iOS, I also tried creating a second Client ID in Google APIs, for an installed application of type "other". I entered this new ID and secret into the sample app, and when I uploaded the .mov file I got the same error.)

Over in the API console, I see an error report showing some new Error code 400s.

What have I done wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just quit and restarted Xcode and the sample project, and it worked (using the iOS client ID, I haven't tried the other one).

Happy days!

Comment: Hi @Racing Tadpole, did you solve your problem. I'm facing exactly the same one you met and nearly give up with it. I quit XCode many times but still not solved

Comment: Sorry, just restarting XCode worked for me... Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Racing Tadpole, I solved my problem, just because the title of video is empty string and cause this error, so stupid. Thanks your post anyway

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube API packs a "structured error" object inside of the `NSError` object that it returns. The structured error is a `GTLErrorObject` that can be inspected to find the reason for the error:

```
uploadTicket = [service executeQuery:query 
                   completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket* ticket, id object, NSError* error) {
    if (error) {
        GTLErrorObject* const errorObject = error.userInfo[kGTLStructuredErrorKey];
        NSLog(@"error from YouTube API: %@", errorObject.data);
    }
    ...
}];
```

Sample output (formatted for clarity):

```
error from YouTube API: (
    GTLErrorObjectData 0x7fb0c4cc9f10: {
        message:"Bad Request" 
        locationType?:"other" 
        reason:"invalidCategoryId" 
        domain:"youtube.video" 
        location:"body.snippet.categoryId"}
)
```